# Determine when method enters or exists with custom attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postsharp, system.diagnostics

[PostSharp](http://doc.postsharp.net/logging?utm_source=vsx&utm_medium=app&utm_campaign=Learn) has a feature that logs when methods are entered and exited just by using an attribute on the method. I'd like to mimic the same idea, but I'm not sure how they achieved this.

```
[Log] 
public void Save(string firstName, string lastName, string streetAddress, string city) 
{ 
    var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(); 
    customerRepository.Save(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city); 
}
```

What do I need to build in order to do this?

Comment: Postsharp decompiles your code after the normal compilation step, then adds more code from the attribute into the code, then recompiles it. It basically rewrites your code and adds things to your methods. There is no way to do this without a tool similar to Postsharp. There are *some* things in .NET you can use but they tend to have severe downsides as they are meant for different things like proxy handling and such.

Comment: that is called Aspect-Oriented Programming, there is an article on their site which describes it a little. [Aspect-Oriented Programming on .NET Framework](https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net)

Comment: The *some things in .NET* which I mention above is shown in the article @Mark reference: https://www.postsharp.net/aop.net/runtime-weaving - RealProxy, ContextBoundObject. But these are heavy-handed solutions and comes with some downsides.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Oh, I figured something intensive was happening behind the scenes. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any such built-in feature present in `C#` but why can't you simply print a line to the console/file like below

```
public void Save(string firstName, string lastName, string streetAddress, string city) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Method Entered @ {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
    var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(); 
    customerRepository.Save(firstName, lastName, streetAddress, city); 
    Console.WriteLine("Method Exited @ {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```